# performance.timeOrigin returning a date in the past

Tags: performance, google-chrome

After updating to Chrome 105, I noticed while debugging that I was seeing some really incorrect values when attempting to calculate TTFB on our website, and realized that in certain browser tabs I'm getting incorrect values for `performance.timeOrigin`.

Some sample output from the devtools console:

```
new Date()
> Mon Sep 19 2022 13:56:37 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
new Date(performance.timing.responseStart)
> Mon Sep 19 2022 13:56:14 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
new Date(performance.timeOrigin)
> Fri Sep 16 2022 21:39:16 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

You'll notice that the first two values are correct, while the last is almost 3 days in the past. This incorrect behavior survives reloading the tab, and even opening a new tab, and going to the same domain.

Reloading the tab and checking `performance.timeOrigin` will show that it continues to move forward in time like normal... but still almost 3 days in the past.

Interesting experimental results:

1. Initial tab opened is example.com/a and shows bad `performance.timeOrigin`
2. Opening a brand new tab, go to example.com/b and
   `performance.timeOrigin` will still be bad.
3. I can then type in a new url like google.com and `performance.timeOrigin` is correct.
4. Then typing in example.com/c and `performance.timeOrigin` is bad again.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with hibernating/sleeping the computer, and any domains which were opened in Chrome at that time have their timeOrigin screwed up, but not completely sure.

Closing chrome and reopening seems to have fixed the problem, but I'm wondering if anybody know what exactly caused this?

Answer (score 3):

I've also experience the same thing on Chrome 105, except that it is isolated to timeOrigin from iframe contents. But it looks like your hypothesis with regards to hibernation seems about right - see the following bug opened 5 days ago on Chromium bug tracker:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1365808&q=timeOrigin&can=2

Comment: That makes sense. I began to notice the problem a day after upgrading to Chrome 105.